# SSH aborted the connection when installing numpy in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, numpy, ssh

I'm new to raspberry pi and I want to install numpy version 1.13.3 however when pip starts to run setup.py my terminal freezes for more than 30 minutes and SSH suddenly aborted the connection with the error message "packet_write_wait: Connection to "IP" port 22: Broken pipe". Can you help me to find the right solution for this problem, by the way I'm using Python 2.7.13 and pip 18.1. Thank you in advance!

I tried using "sudo apt-get install python-numpy" however the version is 1.12.1. I also tried editing ssh_config file setting the ClientAliveInterval to 20 and ClientAliveCountMax to 5 but all of these solutions don't work. I think raspberry having a hard time compiling numpy.

[Terminal Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9h0N.png)

Comment: Probably more a configuration/network/Internet problem than something SO can help with.

Comment: Have you tried something like `screen` or `tmux`?  They would allow you to reconnect to the session if the network is unreliable

Comment: did you found a fix? Have the same issue. I tried to run it with nohup in the background but also that fails.